# How to perform actions on Master table transaction in document db

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I want to perform a master table transaction in document db.
I have a one Master table and another one is transaction table, and I want to perform an action on both the table in document db.

Please suggest, did not try any thing.

Not implemented yet.

Please suggest the way so that I can perform actions on Master table and transaction table both in document db like SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking out for event driven/trigger based scenario. You can look out the functionality of [`ChangeFeed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed)

ChangeFeed really works well with Microservices in combination with **[`Azure functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions)**